# Why selenium suddenly "ModuleNotFoundError No module named 'selenium' "?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-chromedriver

It was working the last time I opened the script and now nothing. Imports are the same.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

service = Service(executable_path='chromedriver/chromedriver')
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
        
driver.get(address)
```

All has been updated. pip3 install -U selenium, new chromedriver (117) downloaded, also Chrome for testing.

Any help? it's desperating

Comment: Well, **something** must have changed.  Did you install/update a new version of python?

Comment: Maybe I updated. Too many changes since the chromedriver115 issues, so probably I messed up versions?

Comment: I'm guessing you're using a newer version of python, but `pip3` is still attached to the older version.

Comment: How, exactly, do you run the code?  From the command line?  From an IDE/GUI?

Comment: I run it from visual studio code

Comment: Actually, if I run % python --version, it says Python 3.8.2; if I run % python2 --version, it says Python 3.11.2. And if I run brew update && brew upgrade python3 it says Already up-to-date.
Warning: python3 3.11.5 already installed

Comment: Does it make any sense?

Comment: The general answer to this problem is to choose which version of python you **want** to use, and make sure everything (pip, VS code, etc) is using that version.

Comment: Usually this is done by choosing the appropriate python interpreter inside vs code, and by adjusting your windows PATH variable to add the binary directory for the desired python version, and remove the binary directory for the unwanted version.

Comment: And no, getting a result of `3.11.2` from `python2 --version` does not make sense!

Comment: and how do I fix that?

Comment: Ideally, you shouldn't even have a `python2` command at all.  Is it an actual exe file, or is it a shell alias?